# phone number validation in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

If I have lots of phone numbers like

```
123-456-7890
(111-111-1111
111)-111-1111
(123)-456-7890
```

I just want to match no.1 and no.4, my pattern can only match the no.4, and It seems that the if condition doesn't work.

```
(\()(\d+)(?(1)\)\-|\-)(\d+\-\d+)
```

All the solutions in regex websites can't recognize single bracket.

Comment: You can find in Regex sites like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), check the "Community Patterns" section.

Comment: As I said, those solutions can not filter the single bracket, it's a different problem. @Michał Turczyn

Comment: Please reopen this post as the post isn't only about validating a US number but OP also has a problem as to why his `If Clause` in the regex didn't work which needs a separate explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, which matches either case, with parenthesis OR without parenthesis using alternations,

```
^(?:\(\d+\)|\d+)-\d+-\d+$
```

Also use start/end `^`/`$` anchors to ensure the regex doesn't allow any partial matches.

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/733NQ1/1)**

In case you want to match the number of digits exactly like in sample, you can make the quantifiers more specific and use this regex,

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/733NQ1/2/)**

**Edit: Explanation and correction of OP's regex which uses `If Clause` in regex**

In your regex, you need to turn group1 as optional by putting a `?` after group1

```
(\()(\d+)(?(1)\)\-|\-)(\d+\-\d+)
^^^^ This is mandatory which stops it to match a number that doesn't have ( in start
```

Hence the correct version of your regex should be,

```
^(\()?(\d+)(?(1)\)\-|\-)(\d+\-\d+)$
     ^ You need to add this to make group1 optional so it can match a number without `(`
```

Also, as you can see, I've used `^` and `$` so the regex doesn't allow partial match in the number.

**[Check this demo with your own updated regex, which works like you expected](https://regex101.com/r/733NQ1/3)**

Comment: Nice! And do you know why the if condition doesn't work? have participated in a interview and the interviewer told me use reference.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "back reference". It doesn't directly help here, though, as far as I can see.

Comment: @yanwii: Updated my answer with explanation of why your regex with `If Clause` didn't work as expected and how to make it work. Although like I posted my answer, you can make it work even without `If Clause`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that there are some people don't know how to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(?(?=\()\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-\d{3}-\d{4}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXtAvJ/1)

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of the string

`(?(?=\()\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` - conditional expression: if positiva lookahead `(?=\()` is successfull (what follows is bracket `(`), then match `\(\d{3}\)` - three digits between brackets, otherwise, match `\d{3}` - three digits

`-\d{3}-\d{4}` - match hyphen, three digits, hyphen and four digits

`$` - end of string